# Translate Japanese to Korean

Tags: php, iconv

```
$str1 = '日本の山が好きです。나는 한국사람 입니다.';
$str = iconv("UTF-8", "SJIS//TRANSLIT", $str1);
echo $str;
```

> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Comment: Can't reproduce _that_ error, getting a warning saying _'conversion from "UTF-8" to "SJIS//TRANSLIT" is not allowed'_ across all versions instead, see https://3v4l.org/AsXtA

Comment: @CBroe `iconv` is weirdly platform-dependent, and for whatever reason the version on 3v4l is rather limited.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few misconceptions here:

- "Transliterate" does not mean the same thing as "translate". One is about converting between *writing systems*; the other is about converting between *languages*.
- A character encoding is not necessarily specific to either a writing system or a language, it is just a way of representing characters as binary data.
- [Shift-JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) is a standard primarily designed for representing characters used by *Japanese* text, so if this did work, it would convert *from* Korean text *to* Japanese text, not the other way around.
- The "TRANSLIT" option in `iconv` doesn't promise to map every character in every writing system to some equivalent in any other writing system.

The actual meaning of that option is described [in the PHP manual](https://php.net/iconv) (I've emphasised some key words):

> If the string `//TRANSLIT` is appended to `to_encoding`, then transliteration is activated. This means that when a character can't be represented in the target charset, it **may** be approximated through one or several **similarly looking** characters.

For example, if I run `iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", "é")` the result is `"e"`, because the version of `iconv` I have available has a "transliteration" mapping that says that "e" is "similar looking" to "é".

The error message is simply saying that even with "TRANSLIT" mode turned on, `iconv` can't find any way way to represent [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) characters such as "나" using the Shift-JIS encoding. There is no direct mapping for those characters in the Shift-JIS standard, and it has no rules which define "similar looking" characters to replace them with.